# What is your programming language of choice for a multi-threaded http downloading application?

Tags: multithreading, http, proxy, web-crawler, multiprocessing

I'm eager to learn a new programming language.

Which one(s) would you suggest for a program that:

- downloads millions of URLs, in a multi-threaded manner
- interacts with a DB of some sort to store downloaded data

Think web crawler/search engine styled projects. And know that I'm up for learning literally anything.

Please post your favorite language, why you chose it, and your favorite tutorial/reference manual (preferably free!) for said language.

**Note:** I will update this post occasionally to include everyone's best answers.

Comment: This might not be a good question for SO - it's pretty subjective and there's no definitively good answer.

Comment: How is it any different from "What is the best function to perform X?" Any relevant language can be voted on, the most popular will float to the top. I have seen a ton others like it on SO and am sure that others will benefit from the answers in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`F#` is nice choice, cause the idiomatic patterns of async operations (esp IO) and parallelization is the key strengths of language.

You can do it easy and .NET Framework's BCL is at your service also.

Comment: Thanks for that Jani! I will look into it. According to TIOBE, F# is incredibly unpopular. Is there a lot of good documentation available online would you say? What is your favorite resource? P.S. An answer in 8 minutes at 3am, gotta love stackoverflow!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fsharp/cc835246 and http://langref.org/fsharp/solved and http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2009/05/16/brians-favorite-online-content-for-learning-f/

Comment: http://cs.hubfs.net/ and http://tomasp.net/articles/fsharp-i-introduction/article.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use `Python` for stuff like this. You can use the urllib2 module to download content via HTTP and the I find the syntax of Python to be pleasing.

Furthermore, you can thread easily in Python.

Good Luck.